# Performance Testing Between JMeter and LoadRunner

Tags: performance, jmeter, loadrunner

Some URL response in LoadRunner is not included in JMeter Performance Tool.

Is there a way to add to missing URL responses in JMeter to simulate the same scenario for both tools?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your JMeter configuration. Most probably you didn't check "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" box on the "Advanced" tab of your [HTTP Request sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

[image: HTTP Request Defaults]

If you provide only URL - JMeter will execute the corresponding HTTP Request to that endpoint, however it won't download so called "embedded resources":

- JavaScript files
- Styles (.css files)
- Images

If this is the difference - you can quickly amend JMeter's behavior using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/http-request-defaults).

Comment: From JMeter 3.0 on-wards, `Parsing of CSS imported files (through @import) or embedded resources (background, images, …)`. so, requests originated from `.css` files will also be sent. But, `.js` files won't be processed, so you must take care of those requests originated from `.js` files (typically AJAX requests) manually by adding HTTP Samplers to the Test Script.

Comment: Then can such a JMeter guru explain to me  [this image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVYu6.png)

Comment: First of all, I am not criticizing your answer here, just adding the improvements made in 3.0 version. other thing is that I am also an admirer of your work in JMeter tool and load testing. Now, please read my comment and let me know what I have wrongly informed and I'll correct myself, no hard feelings :-). I'm not talking about parsing `.html` files. Also, I'm the one who upvoted your answer.

Comment: Hi Dmitri - 

Thanks for the insights.

As instructed I already tick the Retrieve All tick box when recording and during running the script but still the URL responses was not added.
I think this URL responses is not part of the application but it is on another application which was an incorporation of our application. 
How to get the URL responses if this is the scenario? 
Thanks! This would be a great help.